# Buffer APi How Convert many rows into a single array?

Tags: php, sql

I have this Api call when user can add unlimited profile_ids

```
 $buffer = new BufferPHP('1/000000000000000000001');
$data = array('profile_ids' => array());
$data['profile_ids'][] = '111111111111111111111111';
$data['profile_ids'][] = '222222222222222222222222';
$data['profile_ids'][] = '333333333333333333333333';
// The text for your update
$data['text'] = $itemtitle;
$data['media'] = array('link' => $link,'picture' => $img) ;
$data['now']= true;
// Uncomment ONE of the lines below if you would like to attach a link or image to your update
//$data['media'] = array('link' => 'http://example.com/');
//$data['media'] = array('picture' => 'http://example.com/images/whiskers.png', 'thumbnail' => 'http://example.com/images/whiskers_thumb.png');
$ret = $buffer->post('updates/create', $data);
 var_dump($ret);
}
```

This profile_ids is stored in my sql database

```
id                   profile_id
1                    11111111111111111111111111
2                    22222222222222222222222222
3                    33333333333333333333333333
```

How can i convert my unlimited sql profile_ids to an array in my API call ?

Comment: Ever heard of JSON?

Comment: Its not really clear what you are actually trying to do. Can you add somemore detail